# Update SharePoint calculated column on Infopath form

Tags: infopath, calculated-column

I have an Infopath 2010 list form that displays a couple of calculated columns. My users have asked if I can make those fields update dynamically while the form is open.

I have already tried moving the calculation to inside Infopath, but an essential component of the calculation is the number of days between two dates. Infopath does not have a DateDiff function and the workaround I found doesn't seem to work in browser forms.

I've also experimented with trying to call the UpdateListItems method of the Lists.asmx web service but I can't get that to work, and besides I don't know if that will work in our authentication environment anyway.